# Capacidade de slices em Golang

Tags: golang, slice

Uma *slice* pode variar com a necessidade, podendo adicionar itens nela, certo? É possível visualizar o tamanho e sua capacidade (`len` e `cap`, respectivamente).

No *tour* por Go, há uma "lição" do [append](https://go-tour-br.appspot.com/moretypes/15), primeiro ele cria um *slice* nula e depois adiciona um 0 a ela e o tamanho fica 1 e a capacidade fica 2. No último `append`, ele adiciona "2, 3, 4" ao *slice* que já tinha 2 de tamanho e 2 de capacidade, e fica com tamanho de 5 capacidade de 8.

Como funciona a capacidade dos *slices* em Go? Como é o "crescimento" dos *slices*?

Aqui está o código:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := []int{2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13}
    printSlice(s)

    // Slice the slice to give it zero length.
    printSlice(s[:0])

    // Extend its length
    printSlice(s[:4])

    // Drop its first two values.
    printSlice(s[2:])
}

func printSlice(s []int) {
    fmt.Printf("len=%d cap=%d %v\n", len(s), cap(s), s)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Um *slice* é composto por 3 membros:

- o endereço onde ele deve começar, que deve ser dentro de um *array* na memória, ou seja, é um ponteiro
- o tamanho para ele saber onde termina, é um inteiro
- a capacidade da fatia que também é um inteiro.

Se o *slice* não é feito em cima de um *array*, um será criado. Um erro comum é achar que ele já é um *array*. São coisas distintas.

A capacidade é quantos elementos é possível usar no *array* que está pegando uma fatia. Quando a capacidade não é suficiente é preciso recriar o *array* com mais capacidade.

Você pode fazer manualmente ou pode usar a função pronta `append()` que faz para você. O algoritmo varia e isto é detalhe de implementação, não conte que crescerá de uma forma específica, se precisa disto faça seu próprio algoritmo. A [implementação atual](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L89).

Há uma realocação de memória, o que pode ser caro em grandes volumes. Então o ideal é já ter um *slice* (*array*) com tamanho exato ou próximo do que precisa usar. Para pequenos volumes muda muito pouco.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Go/Conceptual.md).

Comment: "dobra a capacidade" Não é bem assim. A forma como o `slice` cresce depende tanto da capacidade do `slice` original quanto da quantidade de elementos que serão adicionados. Para quem tem curiosidade, [aqui](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/runtime/slice.go#L89) está a função que coordena o crescimento do slice.

Comment: @FelipeMarinho é, não lembro se me confundi, ou era assim e já mudaram. Eu até ia colocar que isso é detalhe de implementação e esqueci, obrigado.